some web addresses don't answer
I observe surprising symptoms related to networking on my raspberry pi 5.
From time to time, some websites (popular ones, like github.com or this stackexchange) don't answer when pinged. Sometimes, after tens of minutes, they start to work, sometimes they don't.
I checked that the nslookup works, eg.
sygi@raspberrypi:~ $ nslookup github.com
Server:     fd8e:bc72:6d7e:0:6620:9fff:fe19:adb2
Address:    fd8e:bc72:6d7e:0:6620:9fff:fe19:adb2#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   github.com
Address: 20.26.156.215
.
sygi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping github.com
ping: connect: Network is unreachable
sygi@raspberrypi:~ $ ping 20.26.156.215
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

Whereas the same pings work on my desktop in the same local network. The networking setup on the RPI is "manual" connection to the same wifi network (with a fixed static IP and dns of 8.8.8.8) via the graphic interface of xfce. I would like to note that other websites, like google or facebook, as well as connecting via ssh work consistently.

Any idea how to debug this further?

Welcome.   "The networking setup on the RPI is "manual" connection to the same wifi network (with a fixed static IP and dns of 8.8.8.8)" -> Please clarify how this was done by including all the details, including making a reservation on/with the router.

Why would you want to make life difficult for yourself by setting up a static address rather than letting your router do its job?

I didn't do anything on the router. I did this so that I can create alias in a local network to connect to rpi.

There's a few issues here:

When asked properly via a DHCP request, routers may or may not comply with issuing a static address.

If the static address is set by the device without communicating this properly to the router, the address may or may not work for various purposes and that state is subject to arbitrary seeming changes, ie., this is pretty much guaranteed to fail at some point.

If you reserve a static address directly in the router configuration, then
this should work for the device with the corresponding MAC address.  Most home ISP routers should allow for this -- but you have not done so.


You have not mentioned which OS you are using, but you are using XFCE.  If this is RaspiOS, presuming the GUI networking configurator is part of XFCE, it may or very well may not be compatible with the networking stack used (currently topped by NetworkManager, aka. "NM").  That said, if you can do what's mentioned in #3 above, there is a much better chance of it working anyway.  Otherwise, if that configurator doesn't apply itself to NM, you'll have to find a GUI app that does or learn to use NM from the command-line/via editing configuration files manually.
Another option is to give up on the static IP and rely on MDNS/Avahi using a hostname which other device on the LAN will then be able to find.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=avahi

Avahi it isn't specific to the Raspberry Pi world so you may want to look for information elsewhere online for it; their own online docs are pretty skimpy, but you will find some man pages on the system via apropos avahi.
Tip: Make you have something enabled under [publish] in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf; if you aren't actually running any services, use publish-workstation.  The avahi daemon should be enabled by default, check this with systemdctl status avahi-daemon.

Thank you for an extensive explanation. I thought setting the IP "locally" worked as I could access some websites and could ssh successfully, but I think this wasn't the case: the IP worked in the LAN, but I now think it's only the ipv6 that worked (thus big websites worked and others: ~maybe). I have now changed to DHCP setting in the NM + requested this IP be assigned on the router and everything works now. Thanks also for the pointer to MDNS: I wasn't aware of this, but it makes more sense than hardcoding static ips around!
